# How to do mouse over and check the element together with robotframeworks+selenium2libarary

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm going to do automation test on this scenario: when hover the mouse on the button, there will be a float menu. And I want to check the logo in the float menu.
By default, it is:

```
<div class="header fold">
  <div class="logo fold">
  ...
```

When hover the mouse on the button, the page will turn to:

```
<div class="header float-header">
  <div class="logo float-header">
  ...
```

I tried this command:

```
mouse over | css=div.header-status-btn[title="Restore the header"]

page should contain element | css=div.logo.float-header
```

But there is always errors:

> FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'css=div.logo.float-header' did not
>   match any elements.

Seems it can't locate the element in floating menu in this way. 
Anyone know how to check the float menu with mouse over?

Comment: Have you tried locating by Xpath? The HTML of your button is missing but it could work like this: 
`Mouse Over | //header-status-btn[@title='Restore the header']
Wait Until Page Contains Element | //div[@class='logo float-header']`

Comment: I tried but seems "wait until page contains element" does not work. Because before the menu unfolded, the float-header is there but in " hide" mode. so it will be always success even the float-header is not displayed yet

Comment: What about 
`Wait Until Element Is Visible | //div[@class='logo float-header']`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Mouse Over | css=div.header-status-btn[title="Restore the header"]
# wait up to 60s for element to become visible
Set Selenium Implicit Wait | 60   
Wait Until Element Is Visible | css=div.logo.float-header
```